# Detect decimal number and alphabet in string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am writing a mathematical application. How can I detect a number and alphabet in string in c#. For Example:

```
string a = "2x"; // input string
string b = a.Replace("2x","2*x"); // Replace string to add multiplaction sign between a number and variable
```

It could be an integer or double type number.

Comment: That would depend on how you expect your decimal numbers to be formatted. Is two and a half represented by 2.5 or 2,5?

Comment: use regular expressions like val=Regex.Match(subjectString, @"-?\d+").Value . It will give you that number in string form. then you can parse as int by using int.parse(val); method.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(@"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])", "*")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex replace:

```
var math = new Regex(@"\d[a-zA-Z]");            
var expr = "-2X-4Z-5Y";
string replaced = math.Replace(expr, m => String.Concat(m.Value[0], '*', m.Value[1]));
```

output

```
-2*X-4*Z-5*Y
```

UPDATE

if there can be round brackets between coefficient and variable, change replaceas follows:

```
var math = new Regex(@"\d(\()*[a-zA-Z]");
var expr = "10+2(X+5(a+b))";
string replaced = math.Replace(expr, 
                  m => String.Concat(m.Value[0], "*", m.Value.Substring(1)));
```

output

```
10+2*(X+5*(a+b))
```

Comment: Thanks it works just fine. What needs to be changed in case user inputs "2(x)" like this ?

Comment: @Bilal, it  depends. 2(x) can be `2*(x)` or a part of `func2(x)` or `f2(x)`. i think, regex is not enough and you need a smarter expression parser

Comment: What if it is just 2(x) not a function. Is there any solution then?

Comment: How can I modify this to add exception of just one word "log10"? Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: @Bilal, what is wrong with log10? it is not modified by regex, because number is after letters

Comment: The problem is that when input is "log10(x)" it replaces it into "log10*(x)" Rest functions are working fine. I dont know regex expressions so cant modify it on my own,

Comment: @Bilal, i understood. and i think that regex is going to get complex for all possible combinations of numbers, variables, brackets AND log10 as exceptional function. Quick hack is 1. to change notation (e.g. use `lg` instead of `log10`) or 2. reprace `log10` with smth before adding `*` and restore `log10` after. but a solution with an expression parser would be easier to debug and maintain and extend if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Regex.Replace` function.

```
Regex.Replace(@"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])", "*");
```

OR

```
Regex.Replace(@"(\d)([a-zA-Z])", "$1*$2");
```