# Number and Alphabet Separation in a String

Tags: javascript, string, variables, split, alphanumeric

I have String variables in Javascript like :

> var houseNo = "62A"; 
>   var cabinNo = "5BC";

I need to ***fetch out the Integers and the Alphabets separate*** from the string where number of occurrences of each can be any number of times.

Need help to do it in the best possible way, be it through [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) or any other prototype method.

Referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481150/detect-decimal-number-and-alphabet-in-string) but left in vain as don't want it through RegEx.

Comment: Just extract one by one char and compare with digit and compare with alphabets and perform count as per condition

Comment: `jQuery.isNumeric("string")` should be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like :

```
function decompose(string){ 
     for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
             if(parseInt(string[i])){ // if the char is a number?
                // do whatever you want
             }else{
                // it's a character
             }  
      }
}
```

The `parseInt()` function return the number of a giver char. If it is not a number, it returns NaN (not a number). `if(parsInt(char))` return `false` if it's a char, `true` if it's a number

Comment: Thanks @Hearner . Worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var houseNo = "62A"; 
    foreach(char a in houseNo)
    {
        if(a > 48 && a < 57)
        {
         /*it's a number*/
        }
        else 
        {
            /*it's a letter*/
        }
    }
```

You can apply it on every string and determine what you want to do with each number or letter.

Comment: Its a very straight forward and perfect way but its giving an error saying  
" missing ) after argument list " @Shlomi Haver

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "a3434dasds3432s2"
var myString = test.split("").filter(function(v) {return isNaN(v)}).join("")
var myNumber = parseInt(test.split("").filter(function(v) {return !isNaN(v)}).join(""))
```

best to use regex really though.